# Upgrade pip via .ebextensions

Tags: python, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to upgrade pip to possibly resolve a `dist-info directory not found` error, but my deployment appears to just totally ignore any attempts to. Is it possible that installation of requirements happens before any .ebextensions scripts & that's why I'm seeing no progress? If so at what point could I upgrade pip?

I understand I could SSH in, but I don't want to do this for every deploy.

**01_upgrade_pip.config**

```
commands:
  01_upgrade_pip:
    command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Is everything correct here or have the resources I've been following since been deprecated or something?

I have tried including the command in my packages.config as well hoping that'd allow the upgrade to occur first, but still just no indication that it was even acknowledged.

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []

commands:
  01_upgrade_pip:
    command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

I won't include logs for now unless someone requests something specific. Currently all that's relevant there is the same `dist-info directory not found` error alongside the alert that I'm using pip version 9 when 19 is available (confirming no upgrade is occurring).

**Update for Answer Below**
The solution as mentioned below was to use a preinit script.

In **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/08upgradepip.sh**:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: p.s. you can install a hook script in the `files` section of `.ebextensions` as expleined in https://blog.eq8.eu/article/aws-elasticbeanstalk-hooks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use the `preinit` hook?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

> When an instance is launched, Elastic Beanstalk runs preinit, appdeploy, and postinit, in this order. On subsequent deployments to running instances, Elastic Beanstalk runs appdeploy hooks. configdeploy hooks are run when a user updates instance software configuration settings. restartappserver hooks are run only when the user initiates an application server restart.

According to the documentation:

> Place scripts that you want hooks to trigger in one of the subfolders of the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/ folder.

Comment: Could you show me an example of this? I did read that but I'm confused on execution. I tried using `files`, but that fails each time. Would I need a separate .config file to assume proper order?

Comment: No, I don't have an example at hand.

Can you update your question adding what you tried using `files`?
Another option that worked for me was to use Docker instead of the python option.
It's really easy to use and you have `more control over the packages you install.

Comment: I did end up going to Docker route not long after this. I did figure out preinit, however, it still failed. I'll update my question and you can pop it in your answer for future readers.